# Overriding a method versus implementing it multiple times

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class that downloads a news feed from the web

```
public class NewsDownloader {
   public String downloadNewsFast() {
      // download a news feed using a wifi connection
   }

   public String downloadNewsNormal() {
      // download a news feed using a 3g connection
   }

   public String downloadNewsSlow() {
      // download a news feed using a GPRS connection
   }
}
```

In the above case, there are 3 ways to download the news depending on the connection available. As you can see, the aforementioned class defines 3 methods (I know redefining a method applies to static methods in the case of inheritance).

If a client of `NewsDownloader` conditionally calls the download methods based on the connection available like so

```
public class NewsReader {
   NewsDownloader n = new NewsDownloader();

   public void getLatestNews(Connection c) {
      if (c.getType().equals("Wifi")) {
         n.downloadNewsFast();
      }
      else if (c.getType.equals("3g")) {
         n.downloadNewsNormal();
      }
      else {
         n.downloadNewsSlow();
      }
   }
}
```

My question is twofold

1. what problems could I run into designing `NewsDownloader` as depicted above, instead of a more abstract way, using say a factory pattern?
2. what benefits (if any) would the `NewsReader` have with a more abstract design of the `NewsDownloader`?

I have read up on the benefits of the factory method and abstract factory patterns and have implemented them for my own benefit. However, I can't see a difference between the approach depicted above and that of a factory pattern.

I hope people don't see this as trolling! I'm just trying to elucidate the problems that abstract designs solve for a project I'm writing up

Comment: Side advice: don't compare Strings with ==. Use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead.

Comment: I've changed the code. That was a mistake on my part as my code is completely cursory. I made the example above on the fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you restructured like this:

```
public interface NewsDowloader
{
    String download();
}

public class FastNewsDownloader
    implements NewsFownloader
{
    public String download() { /* ... */ }
}

public class NormalNewsDownloader
    implements NewsFownloader
{
    public String download() { /* ... */ }
}

public class SlowNewsDownloader
    implements NewsFownloader
{
    public String download() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Then NewsReader could look like this:

```
public class NewsReader 
{
    public void getLatestNews(NewsDownloader downloader) 
    {
        downloader.download();
    }
}
```

Add a factory to create NewsDownloader instances:

```
public class NewsDownloaderFactory
{
    public NewsDownloader getNewsDownloader(final Connection c)
    {
        final NewsDownloader downloader;

        if(c.getType().equals("Wifi"))
        {
            downloader = new FastNewsDownloader();
        }
        else if(c.getType().equals("3g"))
        {
            downloader = new NormalNewsDownloader();
        }
        else
        {
            downloader = new SlowNewsDownlaoder();
        }

        return (downloader);
    }  
}
```

And then you can put them together:

```
public void foo(final Connection c)
{
    final NewsDownloader downloader;
    final NewsReader     reader;

    downloader = NewsDownloaderFactory.getNewsDownloader(c);
    reader = new NewsReader(downlaoder);    
}
```

Now that you have all of that you have some advantages:

- You can add new NewsDownloader implementations and not have to add code to a whole lot of if/else statements all over your code (assuming you are creating NewsDownloaders in more than one place).
- You have localized the creation (the factory) to a single if/else which makes the code cleaner.

This means that if you add a different type of NewsDownloaders you only have to change the factory and all of the code that uses the downloaders just magically works.

Not having your code littered with if/else statements reduces the number of mistakes you can make by forgetting to modify one of them when you add a new dowloader type.

Comment: Great answer @TofuBeer I am deleting my answer as this is what I explained, also +1 for very explained answer.

Comment: +1 This cleared everything up for me. It was the fact that I had overlooked the possibility of using a `NewsDownloader` instance in **more than one** place, which would require `if/else` statements **everywhere**. This is great, thank you for this

Comment: You also get the advantage with the interface that you can make an existing class a NewsDownlaoder (though I don't like doing that if I can avoid it, one purpose per class is generally better).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what reasons you have in mind for wanting to make things abstract. General rules:

- Abstract classes are for code reuse
- Interfaces define contracts
- Apply Inversion of Control principles, which the factory pattern can sometimes help with

Following those guidelines, I see no immediate reason to think of making an abstract class for NewsDownloader because there's only the one of them. You might make it an interface instead of a class to loosen the coupling, which is the benefit you asked about, I think. Finally, NewsReader shouldn't instantiate its own NewsDownloader, but depend on its being injected in some way.

**Update:** [TofuBeer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052391/overriding-a-method-versus-implementing-it-multiple-times/7052527#7052527) does a great job of laying these principles out in code.

Answer (score 1):

You're not necessarily going to run in to *problems*, but one thought is that when a new network connectivity is invented, you'll need to update both NewsReader as well as NewsDownloader.  If (for example) you used the factory pattern, then you could do it in such a way that you will be returned an object with a downloadNews() method, and the NewsReader class doesn't need to worry about whether it is slow, fast etc; the returned object just needs to have a downloadNews() method and NewsReader will be happy.

But the code you have will certainly work, it's just not considered ideal design.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm chasing. Why isn't it considered ideal design?

Comment: From my experience, the main reason is the one I suggested, in that you have to have the logic in two places.  Ideally, NewsReader shouldn't have to worry about what method to call; it can instead pass to the factory method some information and get an object that is ideal for downloading the news.  It doesn't therefore need to also know the various different method names that it might have to use, it just calls downloadNews() on the object that is returned to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface of a NewsDownloader and create three Concrete classes for downloading in different speeds. and set the property of a NewsReader  (NewsDownloader n) to hold the concrete implementation.

Comment: I would need to set the concrete implementation of a `NewsDownloader` conditionally depending on the network speed. I'm curious as to why an interface would be a good approach?

Comment: because the client will be able to implement his own logic for downloading, and not depend on the code you've written in your downloader class.